# Designing two interfaces to model real-life odometers

Tags: java, interface

all. I was asked to designed two interfaces that model an odometer that we 
  see in daily life. Here is the specification:
   Each odometer consists of wheels of counters.
   Examples of such wheel counters include:

1.A binary odometer whose wheels each show either 0 or 1

2.A desktop date display with three wheels, one each for year, month, and day

3.A dice roll display whose wheels each show the spots for a single die

Write a Java interface for a general wheel counter that has up to four wheels.         Also, write a Java interface for any class that represents a wheel.

I think I have the first interface set up appropriately (correct me if I do misinterpret the requirement as said above). But I do not know how I would to design an interface that represent a wheel. I thought the WheelInterface I created is sufficient for the odometer program. Please help me out over the understanding of the requirement as to how to design an interface to fit my need.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface WheelInterface<T> {

/**Adds a @param wheelType to the @param wheels list
*   @return true if the addition is successful and false if not
*   wheels list (or number of wheels in the list) size must be 
*  over or equal to one and less or equal to four*/

public boolean addWheel(T wheelType, ArrayList<T> wheels);

/**updates a specified @param wheelType value
* if wheelType is numeric then increment the value
 * if wheelType is a string then change the string value*/
public void increment(T wheelType);

/**updates a specified @param wheelType value
*   if wheelType is numeric then decrement the value
*   if wheelType is a string value then update the value*/
public void decrement(T wheelType);

/**resets the all wheelTypes in the wheels list*/
public void resetAll(ArrayList<T> wheels);

/**resets the specified wheelTypes in the wheels list*/
public void resetAll(ArrayList<T> wheels, int index);

/**Get the specified wheel from wheels*/
public T getWheel(ArrayList<T> wheels, int index);

/**Get all wheels*/
public ArrayList<T> getWheels();

/**Calculate all wheel values if the wheel types 
* are numeric*/
public int wheelValues(ArrayList<T> wheels);

/**get wheel string values if the wheel types are strings*/
public String strWheelValues(ArrayList<T> wheels);

/**get wheel value if the wheel type is numeric */
public int wheelValue(T wheel);

/**get wheel value if the wheel type is a string */
public String strWheelValue(T wheel);

/**Get the number of wheels in this collection
*   @return the size of the collection, (the number of wheels)*/
public int getSize();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would start: first of all, you need an `Odometer` interface:

```
public interface Odometer {
    List<Wheel> getWheels();
}
```

And you need the `Wheel` interface.

```
public interface Wheel {
    int getValue(); // let’s deal with numerical values only
    void increment();
    void decrement();
}
```

This is where you can branch out to create specialized wheels… your odometer does not need to know about this.

```
public class BinaryWheel implements Wheel {
    private boolean value;
    @Override public int getValue() {
        return value ? 1 : 0;
    }
    @Override public void increment() {
        value ^= true; // toggle
    }
    @Override public void increment() {
        increment(); // same thing, really!
    }
}

public class YearWheel implements Wheel { … }
public class MonthWheel implements Wheel { … }
public class DayWheel implements Wheel { … }

public class DiceWheel implements Wheel { … }
```

If you need advanced behavior, i.e. the month wheel needs to decrement if you decrement day 1 I would introduce some kind of model that knows about the relationship of the wheels to one another.

But this is basically it. Does this help?

Comment: Yeah, It does help. Thank You.